# Making div fixed when reaching top of window

Tags: jquery

I have found solutions to this and followed them, but haven't gotten it to work, until I tried it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b3ae5re/1/). Somehow, it's working in jsfiddle but not in my project. For me the main disappears when I scroll down the window's height.
This is the js im using. the rest of the code is in the jsfiddle. 
What am I missing?

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
        $('main').css({'height':($(window).height())});
        $('main').css({'margin-top':($(window).height())});
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
        $('main').css({'height':($(window).height())});
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("main");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos > $(window).height()) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Apparently, adding !important to the .stick in the css makes it work. why wouldn't I need that in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you check the Computed CSS in the Developers Tools of the browser you are using? See the difference to correct it. A screenshot for us in case you have not figured out.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are assigning a style attribute to your 'main' div when the page loads.
Style attributes have higher specificity than the selector attribute set in your css.

So when you add the class "stick", the 'margin-top' attribute is not being overridden since it is already assigned by the style attribute which is more specific.

Adding !important to the 'margin-top' property forces it to be the most relevant.